# Application of Ito's isometry in deduction of Wiener Ito Chaos expansion

Tags: probability-theory, stochastic-calculus, brownian-motion, stochastic-integrals, malliavin-calculus

I am trying to learn about the Wiener Ito Chaos expansion and starting reading Oksendal's notes on Malliavin calculus where it is treated in Chapter 1. For a link to the notes, please see http://www.nhh.no/Files/Filer/institutter/for/dp/1996/wp0396.pdf . On page 1.2, in the derivation on the second half of the page, he says he is applying Ito's isometry. What I have a hard time understanding at the moment, is how he can actually do it because the integrands are different? Is this some kind of extension of the general Ito isometry or am I just missing something?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Itô's formula states that

$$\mathbb{E} \left( \left| \int_0^T f(t_n) \, dW(t_n) \right|^2 \right) = \mathbb{E} \left( \int_0^T |f(t_n)|^2 \, dt_n \right)$$

for any "nice" function $f$. Applying this for

$$f(t_n) := \int_0^{t_n} \dots \int_0^{t_2} h(t_1,\ldots,t_n) \, dW_{t_1} \dots dW_{t_{n-1}}$$

yields

$$\mathbb{E} \left( \left| \int_0^T \int_0^{t_n} \dots \int_0^{t_2} h(t_1,\ldots,t_n) dW_{t_1} \ldots \, dW_{t_n} \right|^2 \right) = \mathbb{E} \left( \int_0^T \left| \int_0^{t_{n}} \dots \int_0^{t_2} h(t_1,\ldots,t_n) dW_{t_1} \ldots \, dW_{t_{n-1}} \right|^2 \, dt_{n} \right).$$

Using Tonelli's theorem, we can interchange the expectation $\mathbb{E}$ and the $t_{n}$-integration.  Now the claim follows by iteration.

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer. That part was actually clear to me, apologies for not making it clear which part I meant (I didn't want to copy the whole thing from the notes). I'm struggling with the derivation below where we have (possibly) different functions $f$ and $g$ and where the iterated integrals have different lengths. Again, in that part I understand the last step with the expectation of an Ito integral being zero but I dont get the intermediate part where he applies Ito's isometry. My problem is that I don't see the squared Ito process, I only the product of two (different) integrals

Comment: @sbm Using the polarization identity $$(a+b)^2-(a-b)^2 = 4ab$$ it follows directly from Itô's formula that $$\mathbb{E} \left( \int_0^Tf(s)\, dW_s \cdot \int_0^T g(s) \, dW_s \right) = \mathbb{E} \left( \int_0^T f(s) g(s) \, ds \right).$$ That's exactly what is used there.

Comment: The polarization identity was the missing piece. Thanks!